# DOM CreateElement Unclose Tag Enclosure

Tags: xml, dom, dom-events

How can I unclose a DOM Element? The `<enclosure>` Tag needs to stay unclosed but createElement close the Tag.

**Correct**

```
<enclosure type="image/jpeg" url="image.jpg">
```

**Wrong**

```
<enclosure type="image/jpeg" url="image.jpg"></enclosure>
```

Comment: You can't. Elements in DOM must either be self closed or have an opening and closing tag. But this should not be a problem. Why do you want a non-closing element?

Comment: I think you have a very wrong idea of what DOM is.